# Size Limit on Sending data from Apex method to LWC JavaScript as return paramater

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, list, size, heapsizelimit

While sending the data to Apex , we have limit of around 3MB.
But is there any size limit on sending the data from Apex method as return type to lwc JavaScript.
Since 6MB will hit the heap size limit, definitely we can send less than that, but is there any specific limit as such?

Comment: So the annoying thing is that what fails is the java's JSON serialization, and SF throws an exception but from `Limits` perspective the limit is not hit. It is around 6 mb, practically speaking.

Comment: I don't see such limit, unless you are within 6 MB